# Springboot integration with Jumpcloud LDAP always giving "bad credentials"

Tags: spring-boot, ldap

I'm using the reference code that exist in the official documentation, however, I couldn't make it work. I want to use it with Jumpcloud LDAP:

```
auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=Users,o=mycompany,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=Users")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldaps://ldap.jumpcloud.com:636/o=mycompany,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com")
                .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
```

I tried multiple configurations of this, but all of them are giving me "Bad credentials".

Answer (score 1):

Bad Credentials typically means there was an issue with the LDAP Service account that is required in order to make LDAP queries.  Since JumpCloud does not support anonymous queries you must create an account that has LDAP Bind DN permission.